# After removing xampp and installing mamp, my localhost is Forbidden

Tags: php, apache, xampp, localhost, mamp

I have removed xampp on my mac, and installed mamp.
But when I start mamp and access localhost, my browser shows

> Forbidden
>
> You don't have permission to access / on this server.
> Additionally, a 403 Forbidden error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.

and the icon is still xampp's

[image]

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: The image could just be your browser's cache. When you start MAMP, does it indicate that it has started running properly on port 80?

Comment: if i change mamp ports to 80,443&3306,when i start mamp show that The built-in Apache is active which can cause a port conflict with at least one of your virtual hosts.
It's recommended either to choose a port different than 80 or to stop the built-in Apache.
but i ues sof -n -iTCP:80 | grep LISTEN to check,there is nothing

Comment: Then, i'm sorry, i don't understand. What port is MAMP running on?

Comment: sorry,if i change mamp apache ports to 80,i can't start the servers,so i have to use mamp's default ports

Comment: are you including the port number in the url when you try to visit the site? (for example, if the port is 443, `localhost:443/my/site/index.php`)

Comment: yes, i can visit the index.php ,and my url is http://localhost:63342/htdocs/index.php,but i don't kown what is the ports 63342

Comment: You can visit the index.php? Success? I'm confused, is 63342 the port you set MAMP's Apache server to?

Comment: I‘m sure i can visit the index.php success even i havn't start my mamp,and my mamp's apache port is 8888,maybe i should restart my computer......

Comment: Before you restart, try to visit this url: `localhost:8888`.

Comment: I can visit the locahost:8888 but after restart, i can't visit the index.php,the error is The requested URL /htdocs/index.php was not found on this server.

Comment: ohohoh,wait, i can visit the index.php by phpstorm!!why?

Comment: No idea what to tell you at this point, lol. Never used phpstorm and too tired to stay awake. Good luck!

Comment: Thank you!!!!you help me a lot,hope you have a nice sleep

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! I edited your question to properly format blockquote so that it renders properly - please see the editing help for more information on formatting. I also removed any content that does not add to the question. Please edit in to provide any additional details that's necessary to identify the specific problem. Good luck!